how to get the source dir of the exe file in c#
I created a setup project in Visual Studio.
In this project I need to run a C# application as customer action during installation and I need the path of the setup file (.exe).
How can I get the source directory of the .exe file?
I've tried to use GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName, GetExecutingAssembly().Location, and Environment.CurrentDirectory. All of these functions work from the application, but if I add this program to the setup project as a custom action during installation I get the path: C:\Windows.

Are you sure that's not right?

[Edit] your question and include the code here as text that shows what you're doing? I want to see if you derive from the Installer public class CustomAction : Installer and in the override Install() method  string assemblyPath = Context.Parameters["assemblypath"];

I  override the Install() method,
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
base.Install(stateSaver);
string installerPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Context.LogMessage($"Installer Path: {installerPath}");
}

Read about InnoSetup

you have to added the custom installer to your install project in the Custom Actions pain. Select the Install action and set the CustomActionData property to:
/targetdir="[TARGETDIR]\"

You can get the target directory in the Install methds as below
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);
    string path = this.Context.Parameters["targetdir"]; 
} 

